# Assign same random uuid to every row (Trino)

Tags: sql, presto, trino

I would like to assign the same unique value generated for each row.

I tried approaches here:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/209515/assign-same-random-uuid-to-every-row

but I'm not able to get this to work on trino sql.

Answer (score 0):

To generate guid/uuid in Trino/Presto you can use [`uuid`](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/uuid.html#uuid) function. Based on `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` output it seems that Trino inlines the `uuid()` invocation for following approaches:

```sql
-- sample data
with dataset (id, value) as (
    values (1, 3),
        (5, 2),
        (4, 10)
)
-- query 1
,single_unique_id (unique_id) as (values (uuid()))

select *
from dataset
cross join single_unique_id;

-- or 
-- query 2    

select *
from dataset,
unnest (array[uuid()]) as t(unique_id)
```

You can "fix" it by selecting min/max uuid via [window function](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/window.html) in the result by changing `select *` to `select id, value, min(unique_id) over() unique_id`.

Another hacky approach, possibly a bit more performant one - "hint" by using `min` in subselect:

```sql
-- sample data
with dataset (id, value) as (
    values (1, 3),
        (5, 2),
        (4, 10)
)

-- query parts
,single_unique_id (unique_id) as (values (uuid()))

select *
from dataset
cross join (select min(unique_id) unique_id from single_unique_id);
```

Sample output:

| id | value | unique_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 18fd6f35-876a-4d0d-a8c2-d28f0284662a |
| 5 | 2 | 18fd6f35-876a-4d0d-a8c2-d28f0284662a |
| 4 | 10 | 18fd6f35-876a-4d0d-a8c2-d28f0284662a |